# Destiny: I can't see the next story mission

Tags: destiny

This is going to be supernooby.  I'm very new to Destiny.  I rented it, I don't really like it, and I want to beat it and move on.  I'm trying to play the story missions, but after completing one, I don't see another new mission.  I see level requirements being mentioned when I try to read up about this, but do you seriously have to run around trying to level up just to play the story missions?  I appreciate any info.

Comment: What is the *last* story mission you played? It may simply be hiding on another planet / unclear location (like *The Rift*) or you may need to return to the *Tower* (but yes, there are also some level requirements).

Comment: IIRC you need to visit the Tower after many of the early story missions. You might see a green icon by the Traveler on the map. If you go to the Tower, can you proceed then?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are correct. In order to advance in the campaign, you must also advance in levels. To level up one may play-through the campaign missions to receive xp, play in the [crucible](http://destiny.wikia.com/wiki/Crucible), complete [bounties](http://destiny.wikia.com/wiki/Bounty) and [strike](http://destiny.wikia.com/wiki/Strike) missions as well as other ways. Unfortunately this game is less of a rent for the weekend and more of a spend weeks grinding for weapons and armour in raids and weeklies, so if that is not your desired play style than this is probably not the game for you.

Comment: This is not completely true, you should be able to see the next story mission, regardless of your level (this sounds like the issue the question asker is having).  Being a high enough level to complete it and advance is a different factor.

Comment: That may be the issue but the question that was asked is "do you have to level up to play the story missions", for which the answer is yes. If there are no icons at all then the asker would be experiencing a glitch of sorts and more information would be needed to answer.

Comment: He specifically says "I don't see another new mission"

Comment: Which is a statement not a question, also they have stated that any info is appreciated. Anyway if you would like to contribute another answer to the question that you feel mine failed to address feel free to do so :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're unable to see the next green exclamation mark indicating the next story mission, try travelling to the Reef. Here you have to sit through a cut scene, but then the next mission will be available to you afterwards.

Comment: Do you mean the Reef? And also that should still be marked with a "new mission" icon if that is indeed what you should be doing.

Comment: Thanks I did, edited. I've had it when levelling alts where it doesn't show the new mission icon, but travelling to the Reef was the next step in mission progression. Maybe it is a bug that has since been ironed out?

Comment: Ah. It worked fine on all three of my characters so hadn't realised it was a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without knowing what part you are on. What's the last mission you completed? Do you see and green indicator marks on the planet screen that usually tell you where to go next?

The story is fairly quick to finish in one day and you shouldn't need to worry about leveling up too much in order to complete the story of the game. You will pretty much level up as fast as needed for every following mission until you hit 20 and you're probably done at that point.

The story missions are there pretty much there to get you to level 20 and then you can start doing other things like strikes and raids and crucible to get even better gear that has light levels that get you past level 20 all the way to level 32.